# Convert (raw)request from GET to POST

Tags: http, http-headers

Over here I have http GET request.

```
GET http://www.uw-team.org/hm3next/loguj.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.uw-team.org
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

I want to convert this request from GET to POST method and add some parameters in request body. So I changed first line from

```
GET http://www.uw-team.org/hm3next/loguj.php HTTP/1.1
```

to

```
POST http://www.uw-team.org/hm3next/loguj.php HTTP/1.1
```

and added request body:

```
... 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

param1=val&param2=val2
```

What I have to change/add else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that request body, add:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

That is all you need.

See more information about [POST method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))
and [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

Comment: I would add only that in my case also was required that header: Content-Length: 64

Comment: @MrocznyArturek Ah, yes. I recently found that Apache doesn't need `Content-Length`. For some reason, I assumed that you're using Apache as well. Did you get `411 Length Required`?